# Why is there no forward declaration in concepts c++?

Tags: c++, c++20, forward-declaration, c++-concepts

When I try this example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept only_int = std::same_as<T, int>;

int add_ints(only_int auto&&... args) {
    return (std::forward<decltype(args)>(args) + ... + 0);
}
```

It works... but when I only declare it like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept only_int;

...

// defined later on...
```

It would throw compilation errors.

Is this a missing feature? or it is intended to leave like this?

Comment: Could you mention a use for forward-declared concepts? Because I can't really think of one (can concepts even suffer from circular dependencies?)

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Two concepts with both having member functions taking a template argument of each other's type: `class NodeArchetype { /* ... */ template<Visitor V> void visit(V&&); };` `class VisitorArchetype { /* ... */ template<Node N> void operator()(N&&); };` ps. In fact let me post a new question about whether this is currently possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you could forward-declare concepts, then you could use them recursively. By preventing forward-declaration, there doesn't have to be an explicit provision in a concept declaration to stop you from using them recursively.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can what I would call recursively use a concept, e.g. `template <typename T> concept Selfish = requires(T& selfish) { { selfish.self() } -> std::same_as<T>; };
struct S0 { int self(); }; static_assert(!Selfish<S0>);
struct S1 { S1 self(); }; static_assert(Selfish<S1>);` However I can't forward declare.

Comment: @TooTone: That's not recursion in *concepts*. A recursive concept would be a concept that depends on another concept which itself depends on the first. A concept `A` which `requires B`, and `B` `requires A`.

Comment: It felt similar to me. What's so bad about two concepts recursively using each other? Or should that be another question?