# Two concepts referring each other in their refinements

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Is it possible for two concepts to use each other in their refinements somehow?

Example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept Node = /* ??? */;

template <typename T>
concept Visitor = /* ??? */;

struct NodeArchetype {
  // ...

  template <Visitor V>
  void visit(V&&) {}
};

struct VisitorArchetype {
  // ...

  template <Node N>
  void operator()(N&&) {}
};

static_assert(Node<NodeArchetype>);
static_assert(Visitor<VisitorArchetype>);
```

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045643/why-is-there-no-forward-declaration-in-concepts-c) is why concepts can't be forward-declared (which is the first C++-esque solution coming into my mind for above snippet), related to this question but slightly different.

---

Question is closed already, but here is a failed attempt as requested in comments:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

struct NodeArchetype;
struct VisitorArchetype;

template <typename V>
concept Visitor = requires(V visitor) {
    { visitor.template operator()(std::declval<NodeArchetype&>) } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { visitor.template operator()(std::declval<NodeArchetype&&>) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template <typename N>
concept Node = requires(N node) {
    { node.template visit(std::declval<VisitorArchetype&>) } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { node.template visit(std::declval<VisitorArchetype&&>) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

struct NodeArchetype {
    template <Visitor V>
    void visit(V&&) {}
};


struct VisitorArchetype {
    template <Node N>
    void operator()(N&&) {}
};

static_assert(Node<NodeArchetype>);
static_assert(Visitor<VisitorArchetype>);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/esz169qKh

Comment: What do you *want* to write in the body of the concepts? Ignore the compiler errors, just write it like you are the king of C++.

Comment: It's not really "related"; it's basically trying to solve the same problem. The other question asked about a specific solution, but the overall point is the same: you cannot recurse with concepts. *By design*.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are still replying to that question. Forward-declaration would be one way of solving problem if it were possible but it isn't, which isn't what I asked here. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56741596/7771076) is another valid question with a valid answer working around recursion limitation of concepts in a different use case (so there *are* workarounds for language limitations in some cases). It's okay to leave the question open if you don't have an answer.

Comment: @ofo: That is not a "workaround for language limitations". Deferring to a trait is not the same as recursively using a concept. Traits lack concept subsumption rules, for example. Traits cannot be used in abbreviated template syntax (`func(ConceptName auto T)`). The answer to your question *as asked* is "no". Again, by design.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I updated the question FWIW.

Comment: I don't think you can expect to be able to combine any visitor with any node. Usually visitors are applicable to a specific finite set of node types.

Comment: If I wanted to define a concept, I would write a single concept `template <typename N, typename V> concept VisitableBy = ...`.

Comment: Note that checking these concepts would infinitely recurse, as verifying that (say) `visit` accepted `VisitorArchetype` would involve checking whether `VisitorArchetype` satisfied `Visitor`, which would check whether `NodeArchetype` satisfied `Node`, …