# Why I can't use concept keyword before template argument?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

There has been some talk about how in C++ 20 it is hard to see "kind"(I don't want to say type since that is confusing term when it comes to templates) of template argument. You can read the examples [here](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2021/05/12/template-ambiguity/).

What I was kind of hoping that C++ would allow spammy way to specify that template argument is concept(by prefixing it with the `concept` keyword, but that does not work.

Is there a reason for this, or just nobody thinks it would be useful, since it is a bit long?

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/fzP1GTojP):

```
struct S{
  int x;
};

template <struct S s, /*concept*/std::integral> 
struct S2{
    auto f(){
        return s.x;
    }
};

int main() {
    constexpr S s{47};
    S2<s, short> s2;
    return s2.f(); 
}
```

Here I can help readability(IMHO) by adding struct before S, but concept before `std::integral` does not compile.

Comment: There are no forward declarations of concept. see [why-is-there-no-forward-declaration-in-concepts-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045643/why-is-there-no-forward-declaration-in-concepts-c).

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's because you're specifically *not* supposed to think of it that way. You're supposed to think of `S2` as "taking an `S` and an `std::integral`". The fact that one of those is a struct and one is a concept is reductionist. Satisfy both constraints and you're good.

Comment: Here's a fun quirk. `struct S s` here is equivalent to `class S s`. Now, remove the parameter *name* `class S`... aaand now it's a type template-parameter. One token separates between a non-type parameter and a type parameter. I personally think that sort of context sensitivity is terrible, and since I'm still hopeful to see concepts as template-parameters some day, I'm glad we don't have the ability to put a concept keyword where you show it can't be put.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `struct S` is merely an affordance to backwards compatibility with C. Recall that in C, you *must* prefix the use of a `struct` name (unless you `typedef` it, which is why you see that fairly often in C code). C++ has no such rules, but to allow C++ compilers to compile a subset of C as C++, the developers allowed prefixing typenames with `struct` (or `class`).

There was not a deliberate desire on the part of C++20's authors to grant disambiguation meaning to `template<struct S s>`. It's just how the rules of typenames in C++ work.

Similarly, `concept concept_name` was never considered as a possibility for naming a concept. It is expected that any ambiguity between specific typenames and concepts used constrain type parameters is supposed to be sorted out by the specific name you're using, not the grammar. You're supposed to know that `std::integral` is a concept rather than a specific typename.

For some concept names, this is pretty clear; it's hard to know a lot about iterators and not know that `random_access_iterator` is a concept rather than a specific type. For other names, it is less clear.

Comment: Wrt struct: C legacy is a good point, but it also works for enum... https://godbolt.org/z/67P5Mc9h4

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl - But enumerations are also shared with C... where the proper name for an enumeration is `enum E`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica good point, TILed :D  that you can use enum, but not enum class in template argument(I mean as literal string in source, you can obviously use enum classes as template arguments)